# DBIx::Class Testing Connection

Tags: perl, dbix-class

How can I test if the [`DBIx::Class`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Class) connection that is attempting to be established is successful or not?

I have yet to find a way to test if the connection is made and if not, throw some kind of an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look in the storage sub-object.

https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Storage#connected